# How to call REST services using HTTP methods to download an excel file?

Tags: android, excel, rest, download

I am trying to call the REST Web Services from Android in order to download excel files located on server. Currently, I am able to fetch the files from rest services but am unable to call rest services from android using HttpURL connection. When I try to run the app on emulator, Its shutting down,This is my code

```
URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
throw new RuntimeException("Failed : "+conn.getResponseCode());}
BufferedReader br = new     BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
String output;
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(output);
}
conn.disconnect();
```

This is what I tried till now.
Can please someone suggest me something ?

Comment: Post the logcat output

Comment: are you calling this code from a different thread than the main thread, if not, it will not work.  There are several posts that address this issue